# Generically accessing a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have an Android activity with eight TextViews, named tvStat1, tvStat2, ..., tvStat8.  I have a function that takes an integer as a parameter.  What I want to do is something like this:

```
public void incrementScore(int StatisticCategory){
    String s "R.id.tvStat" + String.ValueOf(StatisticCategory);
    TextView tvGeneric = (TextView)findViewById(s);
    // ... do something with the text in the generic TextView...
}
```

But of course, this doesn't work, since the findViewById method only takes an integer as a parameter, and as such doesn't like my way of identifying a generic TextView based on an incoming parameter.  Since I only have eight TextViews, it isn't too much effort to write a switch statement... but I think there's got to be a better way.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ViewGroup.getChildCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildCount%28%29) and [`ViewGroup.getChildAt()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29). Here is an exmple.

---

Assuming you have layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/text_group"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   />

        <TextView  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   />

        <TextView  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   />

        <TextView  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   />

     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can use next code to assign text to `TextView`s:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout textGroup = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.text_group);

    for(int i = 0; i < textGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        TextView text = (TextView)textGroup.getChildAt(i);
        text.setText("This is child #"+i);
    }
```

### }

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access resources by name at Runtime, see an example [here](http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-_get_resources_by_name__getidentifier_-t460.html).

Regards,
 stéphane